# Set selected text for DropDown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I have a Webgrid with a column containing a dropdown:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("abc", new SelectList(Model.holdTypes),@item.holdType,"")
```

Here `Model.holdTypes` is a `String List`. `@item.holdType` contains the text that needs to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong overload. You should use this version.

```
@Html.DropDownList("abc", new SelectList(Model.holdTypes,item.holdType))
```

While this will render the SELECT element with a selected option, It will generate a SELECT element with only the text, There will not be a value attribute for the option items. So if you are planning to submit the selected option value to a form, This approach might not be very useful. You can use another version for that use case.

```
@Html.DropDownList("abc", 
            new SelectList(Model.holdTypes.Select(v=>new SelectListItem { Value = v,
                                                   Text = v}),"Value","Text",item.holdType))
```

Comment: What you mean not working ? It is not selecting the string value ? It should work as long as `item.holdType` property value is one of the items in the `Model.holdTypes`( I just copied and pasted the line i posted in answer and it worked fine)